# Filter by object array element and return only the value of a field in the array object MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm using MongoDB 5.0.10 and the aggregation pipeline. I am trying to find out if there is a way to filter an array of objects AND return only the value of a field within the returned array object. I can easily filter the array based on a field value within the array. I currently can achieve what I want in 2 stages. I'm just trying to see if I can return a value within the same stage. I'm using a projection and $arrayElemAt to filter the array. Then I perform another projection to get the value I want.

Sample document:

```
{
  "_id": 1,
  "lastOpenedList": [
    {
      "_id": 4,
      "dateTime": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "1659970718606"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

First stage:

```
$project: {
'lastOpened':{$arrayElemAt: [
    {$filter: {
      input: "$lastOpenedList",
      cond: {
        $eq:[
          "$$this._id", '4'
          ]
      }
    }},0
    ]}
}
```

Second stage:

```
$project: {
'lastOpened': '$lastOpened.dateTime'
}
```

Result:

```
{
  "_id": 1,
  "lastOpened": 
    {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "1659970718606"
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query

- filter can't change the member only keep it or not
- we have 2 options `$map` + `$filter` => map keep those we want, and null in others, and then with `$filter` remove those nulls
- other option is $reduce, and keep only those we want, in general $reduce is the most powerful
- here `$reduce`, and if match keep it

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=62f12eca78a49d8782851478)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$project": 
   {"_id": 0,
    "lastOpened": 
     {"$reduce": 
       {"input": "$lastOpenedList",
        "initialValue": null,
        "in": 
         {"$cond": 
           [{"$eq": ["$$this.dateTime", 2]}, "$$this.dateTime",
            "$$value"]}}}}}])
```

Comment: Thank you! This seems right but did you mean {"$eq": ["$$this._id", 5]}... instead of {"$eq": ["$$this.dateTime", 2]}? I need to filter by the _id in the array object. I changed your Playmongo to filter by id and it returns what I want, if I change the id value passed into the function.

Comment: ok good i wasnt sure what exaclty output you need, but this is common way, reduce or map+filter(remove nulls)